# Is there a way to extrapolate a distance reading from a PointCloud data stream?

Tags: ros, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, lidar

I'm currently working with a Livox Avia LiDAR and I'm utilising ROS to access its data stream which is in the PointCloud2 format.
A LiDAR is mainly use to measure the distance an object in the boresight to the LiDAR.

Does anyone know how to read off a distance from PointCloud2?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be a little more specific in what you mean by "read off a distance" since there are multiple distances that could be of use when talking about PC2 data. I'm assuming you're talking about distance from the sensor to a single measured point. If that's the case, you can pull out more usable information from pointcloud data with
the generator function `read_points()` to get (x, y, z) and then calculate distance directly. You can grab all points in x, y, z format like this:

```
from sensor_msgs import point_cloud2
def pc2_callback(msg):
    generator = point_cloud2.read_points(msg, skip_nans=True, field_names=("x", "y", "z"))
```

Comment: Thanks @BTables for your help.
This is a bit of a weird one but if I've got a single object in the boresight of my LiDAR what is the best way of selecting the points that are useful.
On average, after getting rid of the null values (not NaN but 0), I'm getting about 11,000 points out of the origial 24,000.

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by useful in this context. If you're looking for points that correlate to one, or more, specific objects there's really no reason to be stripping 0 values out of the pointcloud; you should however be doing ground plane stripping. You can find objects by grouping points via a method like k-means clustering. Have the object as a 3D bounding box is almost always better than having it as PC2 data.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I've nailed it.

Comment: For those interested, if your only interested in the point cloud data for one object you could ignore certain points to create what is essentially a search tunnel.
I can say from experience this works a treat although finding the right value for my if statement was very much trial and error.